# Estimation of the size of a real black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, astronomy

Consider for example the black hole in the centre of the Milky Way. I know we can calculate the corresponding mass just by looking at the orbits of near stars. My question is: **how do we estimate (experimentally) its size?** I have heard that we can obtain information about the size from the luminosity curve, but I do not understand how. Any ideas?

**Note**. By 'size' I mean a typical size: ~ the Schwarzschild radius or a few Schwarzschild radius estimated exclusively through observation.

Comment: The 'size' of a black hole is a difficult thing to define. The location of it's event horizon - one measure of its size - is easy to calculate, depending on the type of black hole in question. For an uncharged, non-rotating black hole, the Schwarzchild radius R is just proportional to it's mass, $R = 2GM$. Some other measure of size might come from gravitational lensing, although this will always give a result bigger than the Schwarzchild radius.

Comment: Let me clarify what I mean by 'size' in the question (edited).

Answer (score 1):

The observational evidence would include the light from the accretion disk and gravitational lensing. But I would bet that this evidence would be consistent with a size that was two or even three times the Schwarzschild radius.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the size is taken to be the Schwarzschild radius, $r_s$, which is given by $\frac{2GM}{c^2}$. This would be calculated using the mass, which can be found using the technique you mention in your question.

Of course, this doesn't refer to the accretion disk that would most likely be surrounding the hole. However the luminosity of the disk means that it would be directly observable.